# Solver error in SciPy/LSODA with a very specific parameter set

Tags: python, ode, scipy

I'm implementing a very simple Susceptible-Infected-Recovered model with a steady population for an idle side project - normally a pretty trivial task. But I'm running into solver errors using either PysCeS or SciPy, both of which use lsoda as their underlying solver. This only happens for particular values of a parameter, and I'm stumped as to why. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import scipy.integrate as spi

#Parameter Values
S0 = 99.
I0 = 1.
R0 = 0.
N0 = S0 + I0 + R0
PopIn= (S0, I0, R0, N0)
beta= 0.50     
gamma=1/10.  
mu = 1/25550.
t_end = 15000.
t_start = 1.
t_step = 1.
t_interval = np.arange(t_start, t_end, t_step)

#Solving the differential equation. Solves over t for initial conditions PopIn
def eq_system(PopIn,t):
    '''Defining SIR System of Equations'''
    #Creating an array of equations
    Eqs= np.zeros((3))
    Eqs[0]= -beta * (PopIn[0]*PopIn[1]/PopIn[3]) - mu*PopIn[0] + mu*PopIn[3]
    Eqs[1]= (beta * (PopIn[0]*PopIn[1]/PopIn[3]) - gamma*PopIn[1] - mu*PopIn[1])
    Eqs[2]= gamma*PopIn[1] - mu*PopIn[2]
    return Eqs

SIR = spi.odeint(eq_system, PopIn, t_interval)
```

This produces an error:

```
 lsoda--  at current t (=r1), mxstep (=i1) steps   
       taken on this call before reaching tout     
      In above message,  I1 =       500
      In above message,  R1 =  0.7732042715460E+04
Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type).
Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
```

However, changing "mu" (which is currently 1/70 years, a pretty common value for life expectancy) to either 26550 or 22550 produces no such error, though some values between 25550 and 22550 seem to.

I'm a little puzzled as to why that combination in particular is producing errors. Anyone have some insight?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your system blows up slightly above t=7732. You can check this by setting t_end=7732 and plotting the result using -

`plot( SIR[:,0] ); show()`

Your differential equation might have a problem.

Comment: There's clearly something wrong, but having stared at it, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: The initial condition is a vector of length 4 whereas the function returns a vector of length 3. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the derivative of one of the functions is already machine precision 0 as the error also indicates. Your entire ODE system evolves within `tend < 150` and is in steady state during the next following 14850 steps. At some point the derivative between two consecutive time steps is evaluate to 0.